# Why doesn't extractWars work in Jetty 8.1.10?

Tags: jetty, war

Here is the definition of extractWars:

```
If parameter is true, any packed WAR or zip files are first extracted to a 
temporary directory before being deployed. This is advisable if there are 
uncompiled JSPs in the web apps.
```

But when I set extractWars to false, my app doesn't work any more. My app doesn't have any JSP.

Comment: this is a duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493359/why-must-jetty-extract-war-files

Comment: if you have any errors, logs, or stacktraces, then edit your question to include them.

Answer (score 0):

What is the failure you get?   Typically if you don't extract a war any webapp that attempts direct access to resources as Files is going to fail.

Comment: It cannot find web services. Also it still create a temp directory, though it is empty inside.